# Quick check of Tridion Link Propagation

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Just when I think I understand how Tridion resolves links ....

According to the docs about Component links -

> If you unpublish a Component, any Components that link to that
>   Component are **not unpublished**.

Does this only relate to DCPs?

We have components used in DCPs and within component links. When I unpublish the component e.g. C5, in the "items to unpublish" list, I see pages that are only connected to C5  through component links - I've opened several pages from the list and none use the component directly in a CP, but it is linked to from another component on the same page:

```
Page P1
        CP1
            C1 + CT1
        CP2
            C2 + CT2
            (C2 links to C3 below)

Page P2
        CP1
            C3 + CT3
        CP2
            C4 + CT4
            (C4 links to C5 below)

Page P3
        CP1
            C5 + CT5
```

When I unpublish the component C5, Page P1 is in the unpublish list - that's correct behaviour right?

**EDIT**

Apologies, this is Tridion 2011 SP1.

Comment: Neil, Which version of 2011 GA vs SP1 ? If it is SP1, check this hotfix "CM_2011.1.0.79124". Few months back, we find this hard way. :)

Comment: Will do - updated question to reflect version. So the behaviour we've witnessed is wrong then?

Comment: In your case, you should notice P3, P2 not P1. That is what I can recollect we noticed. The behavior you're noticing is little odd, bcuz you see at the minimum P3 because C5 is on that page.

Comment: Yeah we do see P3 - I'm just trying to understand why P1 is there too!

Comment: Are all of your CTs set to "Dynamic and allow placing on a page"?

Comment: No, in this example only CT5 is set to "Publish as Dynamic Component" and the "Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly" checked. This others are "Published Embedded on Page".

Answer (score 2):

I would think that is indeed the wrong behavior. Unpublishing of a component should not unpublish all the pages containing components with component links to the component we are unpublishing.

**EDIT**

@Neil, the only things I can think of that could trigger the behavior you describe are the following:

1. 2009 or older. TBB, Workflow or EventSystem with code to publish/unpublish
   components according to your description.
2. 2011 GA or newer. TBB, Workflow, EventSystem or resolver extension with code to trigger the behavior you explain in your post.
3. Unlikely but is still possible, a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

Unpublishing C5, as a DCP used by a page and static content, should:

- Leave P3 alone, since it includes C5 as a dynamic Component Presentations
- Unpublish C4 and as a (non-dynamic) component embedded on a page, this will also...
- Unpublish P2 (if already published)

The question is if unpublishing P2 should unpublish C3 and therefore C2 and the P1 page it's embedded on (statically). Unpublishing a page with a non-dynamic embedded CP doesn't unpublish other pages at least for my SDL Tridion 2011 SP1-1 setup.

But, because the dynamic component is linked to by a "static" component, I'm thinking the best case here is to remove and publish the page. Otherwise you'll have other pages like P2 removed if you really just meant the DCP.